# Facebook Graph Not Getting All Photo Posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all posts from a facebook page for the last two years. Access token is my own which has manage_pages, publish_pages, show_page_list.

The posts are there, they're moderately old early 2016, but, graph doesn't bring them back these older ones. They were scheduled posts, visibility=everyone and of 'photo' type. Any query on {page}\feed, {page}\photos, or {page}\posts yields only a couple of posts.

Facebook Insights Screenshot
https://pasteboard.co/Hde6ZWU.png

Graph Explorer Output Screenshot
https://pasteboard.co/Hde7iDP.png

Does anyone know how to enumerate these posts with graph, or know of the reason why graph isn't reporting them using the get/feed and get/photos command?

Answer (score 0):

These aren’t photos, they are posts.

```
1409847682673697/posts?since=2016-01-01&until=2016-02-01
```

shows the first post from your dashboard screenshot, “Andrew Smith - Malta”, just fine.

This is a *share* of a post onto your page only - the “original” is https://www.facebook.com/andrewmsmithart/photos/a.1533059820295875.1073741827.1533035286964995/1648921165376406/ But since that is not a photo uploaded by your page nor has your page tagged in it, naturally it doesn’t show when you request your page’s photos.

The `object_id` field of your page post refers the actual photo object.

Comment: Thanks, that does it. My lack of understanding was I didn't see the pagination and thought the default 25 was the complete resultset.